# Angular 2: Observable not returning the object (nested) from service

Tags: angular, typescript, nested, observable, angular2-services

I have an angular service which returns the user object. The user object has its own attributes plus an array of walls. The service returns an observable to the calling component. In the service, I am able create a user object from the json returned by the http service. However, when I subscribe to the service in my component, the object returned is null. What am I doing wrong here?

```js
// user.ts

import { wall } from './wall';

export class user {
    Id: number;
    EntryType: number;
    UserType: number;
    SubscriptionType: number;
    IsCoach: boolean;
    Username: string;
    Email: string;
    Name: string;
    Password: string;
    Created: string;
    MemberWalls: wall[];
}
```

```js
//wall.ts
export class wall {
    Title: string;
    ViewItem_Id: number;
}
```

```js
//authentication.service.ts

authenticate(authRequest: login): Observable<user> {
        let url: string = this.apiUrl + AppSettings.LOGIN_SERVICE;
        let headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': AppSettings.CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER, //'; charset=utf-8',
            'client-secret': AppSettings.CLIENT_SECRET,
            'client-id': AppSettings.CLIENT_ID
        });

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this._http.post(url, authRequest, options) // 
            .map(data => {
                this.authenticated(data);
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);

    }

    private authenticated(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        if (body.StatusCode === 200) {
            localStorage.setItem('auth_token', res.headers.get("access-token"));
            let user1: user = body.Data;
            //The user object is fine here. 
            //That means that the json and the user class structure match perfectly
            console.log(user1);
            return body.Data || {};
        }
        else {
            return {};
        }
    }
```

```js
//login.component.ts

login() {
        this.errorMessage = '';
        this.currentUser = null;

            this._authService.authenticate(this.loginModel)
                .subscribe(user1 => this.currentUser = user1,
                error => this.handleError( error));

  //The user1 returned by the service is always null.
    }
```

Comment: How do you know it is null?

Comment: `user1 => this.currentUser = user1,` is a function that is called when the data arrives.  Code at the place where you have your comment is executed loooong before that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accepting answer from Gunter:

`user1 => this.currentUser = user1`, is a function that is called when the data arrives. Code at the place where you have your comment is executed loooong before that

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the **return** statement when mapping the result of the post request.

In es6 and ts:

- When an arrow function is defined using brackets, return statement is mandatory.
- When an arrow function is defined without brackets, es6 autogenerate a return statement returning the value of the expression provided after the arrow sign

Ex:

```
let f = (data) => this.authenticated(data);;
// Or 
let f = (data) => { return this.authenticated(data); };
```

Comment: I think this would be useful to at least try @Shilpa Nagavara.